# wrapCallback is not defined in unity webapps

Tags: unity, webapps

Here is what i trying. I am loading a this code in a js file on my site. Error seams to be util.js is not getting loaded

```
// ==UserScript==
// @require       utils.js
// ==/UserScript==

window.Unity = external.getUnityObject(1.0);

function setupMyApp(){
    var total = 10;
    Unity.Launcher.setLauncherCount(total);
}

Unity.init({ name: "MyApp",
    iconUrl: "http://localhost:5000/static/icons/icon.png",
    onInit: wrapCallback(setupMyApp)
});
```